# Empty intent filter gives me problems

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have an application that needs to start and stop activities.

So far we are OK with starting the Activity.

The problem comes when I try to stop the Activity.

This is the AlarmManager that broadcasts the intent to close the activity:

```
        Intent ftue = new Intent(ctxt, VideoActivty.class);
        ftue.putExtra("finish", true);
        PendingIntent pftue = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, ftue, 0);
        Calendar calSet4 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calSet4.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calSet4.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calSet4.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 3);
        calSet4.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hftue);
        calSet4.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mftue);
        calSet4.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet4.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        //calSet.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet4.getTimeInMillis(),
                7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pftue);
```

And in my Activty I have implemented a BroadcastReceiver that should shut down the Activty.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
IntentFilter f=new IntentFilter();
registerReceiver(receiver, f);
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
super.onPause();
}

BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("","intento ricevuto");
        if(intent.getBooleanExtra("finish",false))finish();

    }
};
```

My application does not receive the broadcasted intents, and I understand that is because the intent filter is empty.

**Please how should I implement the intent filter to receive the broadcasts?**

Thanks!

Comment: Also, If your Activity is paused, it won't receive the broadcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why your intent filter is blank? You can write intent action as any string (BUT that should not exists in SDK Actions)*

// like

```
IntentFilter f = new IntentFilter("com.android.INTENT_ACTION_TO_CLOSE_ACTIVITY");
```

And use

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent("com.android.INTENT_ACTION_TO_CLOSE_ACTIVITY");
sendBroadcast(mIntent);
```

at the condition, when you want to close the Activity.

Comment: May I know what happend with you?

Comment: Kumarn sorry, I thought it didn't work when I tested, but I found the problem and fixed it. Thanks a lot Pankaj !!!!!